# Select all values with the same key in a dict

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary

I am using an API to get some financial data from companies.

API https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/financials/income-statement/TD

How can I select all values for the key revenue?

```
import urllib.request
import json

income_statement = ('https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/financials/income-statement/TD')

response = urllib.request.urlopen(income_statement)
parseResponse = json.loads(response.read())

test = (parseResponse['financials'][0]['Revenue'])
```

This will give me the number, but not for all key = Revenue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to loop through the `financials` array and stored all the revenues inside another array. Something like

```
all_revenue = [item['Revenue'] for item in parseResponse['financials']]
```